# Errors in making QTDCM

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have started using QTDCM by the steps in This web site:
[QTDCM](http://qtdcm.gforge.inria.fr/html/step2page.html) 
But when I tried to this instruction :
**make && sudo make install-all**
 I had these errors:

```
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_write_info'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_write_image'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_set_text'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFFlushData'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFFdOpen'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_convert_from_time_t'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_write_end'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_set_tIME'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `png_access_version_number'
../../dcmimage/libsrc/libdcmimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFGetVersion'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dcmdjpls] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/../qtdcm/dcmtk-3.6.0/dcmjpls/apps'
make[1]: *** [apps-all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/../qtdcm/dcmtk-3.6.0/dcmjpls'
make: *** [dcmjpls-all] Error 2
```

Comment: You are probably missing the correct libraries.

Comment: Well, I completely used this instruction step by step :  http://qtdcm.gforge.inria.fr/html/step2page.html  and did not miss any thing